# Jelly script needed

Tags: service, jira, jelly

Is jelly capable of running as service to increase a custom field by a value of 1 at midnight each day?

for example:

1 = day 1

2 = day 2

3 = day 3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the Script Runner service over Jelly